# Rails: Creating a Search Filter Based on Dropdowns for Mongoid Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

On my index page I have a few dropdowns that the user can select as a filter for searching a Mongo collection. These dropdowns correspond to fields set in my model. There is also an open text input field they can use to search the text fields "scenario name" and "scenario body" in the collection. I can't seem to find much of any documentation on how to chain Mongoid queries to narrow down search results.

The index.erb view page has a `form_tag` with various selectors for the fields I want the user to search on, and a text input for the scenario name and body fields.

Here is my Index Controller:

```
  def index
@scenarios = if params[:search]
               Scenario.search(params)
             else
               Scenario.all
             end
end
```

And my "scenarios" model:

```
class Scenario
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :submitter, type: String
  field :scenario_name, type: String
  field :scenario_body, type: String
  field :creation_date, type: Date
  field :modified_date, type: Date
  field :test_type, type: String
  field :application, type: String
  field :pillar, type: String

  def self.search(search)
    self.or({submitter: /.*#{search[:submitter]}.*/i},
            {scenario_name: /.*#{search[:search]}.*/i},
            {scenario_body: /.*#{search[:search]}.*/i},
            {creation_date: search[:creation_date]},
            {modified_date: search[:modified_date]},
            {test_type: /.*#{search[:test_type]}.*/i},
            {application: /.*#{search[:application]}.*/i},
            {pillar: /.*#{search[:pillar]}.*/i})
  end
end
```

How should I go about creating a method or query that can filter on one, many, all of the dropdown options and an open text search?

Comment: What do you want that field to filter? another field on the mongo document? one of the already defined fields? you can do `.where(field: params[:open_field]) if params[:open_field].present?` or something like that, I think you can explain this clearer.

Comment: @arieljuod, i would like the selected dropdown fields to filter the search result of the "scenarios" collection in Mongo.I have a dropdown option of "austin" for the submitter field, which only brings back documents with a submitter of "austin". These should chain together for the other fields as well. I will update the question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I went about it. Does not seem very rails-like at all though, but it works.

In Scenario model:

```
  def self.search(search)
    search_array = [{scenario_name: (/.*#{search[:search]}.*/i if search[:search].present?)},
                    {scenario_body: (/.*#{search[:search]}.*/i if search[:search].present?)}]

    search_array.map {|a| a.reject! {|k, v| v.nil?}}
    search_array.delete_if {|hash| hash.empty?}

    select_array = [{submitter: (search[:submitter] if search[:submitter].present?)},
                    {test_type: (search[:test_type] if search[:test_type].present?)},
                    {application: (search[:application] if search[:application].present?)},
                    {pillar: (search[:pillar] if search[:pillar].present?)}]

    select_array.map {|a| a.reject! {|k, v| v.nil?}}
    select_array.delete_if {|hash| hash.empty?}

    mongo_query = ['$and' => (select_array if select_array.present?), '$or' => (search_array if search_array.present?)]
    mongo_query.map {|a| a.reject! {|k, v| v.nil?}}
    mongo_query.delete_if {|hash| hash.empty?}

    where(mongo_query[0]).to_a
  end
```